# help in solving a problem in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I have aquestions from you.
Does SQL server have any features so we can limit a field to fill with just specific values? For example assume that you have a field named "Name" then we want SQL just let us to fill this field with the following values:
"Bella", "Jack", "Rose".
is there any featues to do it? please guide me. thanks

Comment: accept one answer... both are correct. One gave you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Check Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)

Comment: ADD CONSTRAINT checkValues CHECK Names in ('Rose', 'Bella', 'Jack');

Comment: @elton, it should works, if it does not works you can use: ADD CONSTRAINT checkValues CHECK (Name = 'Rose' or name ='Bella' or Name = 'Jack'));

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YOUR_TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_name CHECK (name IN ('Rose', 'Bella', 'Jack'));
```

...but you might want to [use a separate table & foreign key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177463.aspx) if you need to add identical CHECK constraints to numerous tables:

### NAMES

- name_id (primary key)
- name

Foreign Key Constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YOUR_TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_names FOREIGN KEY (name)
REFERENCES dbo.NAMES (name_id) ;
```

Comment: Good point about using a foreign key but whether it is a good idea to introduce `nameid` into the schema is another matter... or possibly just a typo ;)